# Chrome removing url parameters

Tags: typescript, google-chrome

I am building an angular application, I want to pass an id in the browser for some functionalities. It works fine in IE, however in chrome the browser strips the /id from the url and just displays the base url and the application cannot retrieve the id. Can you please help?

```
getIdForEdit(): number {
    if (window.location.href != null && window.location.href.trim() != "") {
      if (window.location.href == this.sitePathName ||
        window.location.href == this.sitePathName.concat("#/")) {
        return 0;
      }
      var id = + window.location.href.replace(this.sitePathName, "").replace("#", "");
      if (id > 0) {
        return id;
      }
      else {
        return 0
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: We can help, but we'll need to see some code.  Please provide us with a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by adding an extra # to the URL. So if we have www.mysite.com/#/123 the 123 will stay in the address bar.